# Is there an Unicode code point for umlauts marked with a small e instead of a diaresis?

Tags: unicode, accents, characters

The original way to denote an umlaut in German was to write a small e on top of the umlauted letter, like in the second row of the image below. Is this form of the umlaut availabe via Unicode? In LaTeX, you can use the package `yfonts` and then the command `\*` to get such an umlaut, but I am not sure whether there is a regular codepoint for letters umlauted this way.

[image: Umlaut comparison]

#### Offtopic

I think, this is a bit offtopic, but since I don't know where to post this, I post it here because I find tex.SE the place where the people are most likely to answer this question.

Comment: `a`+ `U+0364 COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER E` = aͤ. Font support is another question.

Comment: Wow. At least with linux libertine, it works. Thank you!

Comment: @Caramdir: please add your comment as answer :)

Comment: @Philipp: I didn't because I also voted as off-topic.

Comment: I'd agree on 'off-topic': as a mod, I'll wait and see what the voting looks like.